# Unable to use enumerate outside of training loop pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I was experimenting with python and pytorch before I stumbled upon this issue, `enumerate` doesn't seem to be working on my dataloader without putting it into a training loop.

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Code:

```
 for i, data in enumerate(train_dl):
      image,labels = data
```

Outputs:

```
'tuple' object is not callable
```

However when I put it into a training loop it somehow works, there are no errors for the code below.

```
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # origin shape: [4, 3, 32, 32] = 4, 3, 1024
        # input_layer: 3 input channels, 6 output channels, 5 kernel size
        images = images.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

This is the data

```
mean = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
std = np.array([0.25, 0.25, 0.25])


transform_train =  transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean, std)
    ]),
transform_val =  transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean, std)
    ]),

train_ds = ImageFolder("/content/data/cifar10/train",transform_train)
val_ds = ImageFolder("/content/data/cifar10/validate", transform_val)

train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size = 32, shuffle=True, num_workers=2, pin_memory=True)
val_dl =  DataLoader(val_ds,batch_size = 32,shuffle = False, num_workers=2, pin_memory=True)

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

trainning_dataset_size = len(train_dl)
val_dataset_size = len(val_ds)
```

Comment: Can you share what's there inside train_dl, please make sure you have not assigned something to enumerate.

Comment: train_dl consists of 65000 images from the Cifar-10 dataset of batches 32.I will update the code accordingly

Comment: Pretty sure you've accidentally overwritten `enumerate()` somewhere in your code.

Comment: I have doubled checked the codes, there are no `enumerate()` written anywhere else